# Convergence of random walk on $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ with $m$ even to its invariant distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Consider the simple random walk on the circle $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ with $m$ even and transition probabilities $P(i,i+1)=P(i,i-1)=\frac{1}{2}$. This Markov chain is clearly irreducible, hence it has a unique invariant probability measure $\pi$. However, since the chain has period $2\neq 1$, it does not necessarily converge to $\pi$ in terms of total variation distance.

**Question:** Are there examples of even numbers $m\in\mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$ such that the chain does not converge to $\pi$? Does there exist any such $m$ such that the chain converges?

Comment: For $m$ even, the graph is bipartite, so if the random walk starts on a partition, it will be in that particular partition after an even number of steps. In particular, the probability distributions for even and odd times are supported on different partitions and hence convergence is impossible. Just think about $\mathbb Z \over 2 \mathbb Z$,  the random walk just goes $0 \to 1 \to 0$ and so on (with probability $1$ on each occasion), so convergence is out of the question.